# Handle Stripe errors in Slim PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments, slim

I'm struggling to find a solution to handle the error messages from Stripe in Slim. When I get a response back Slim is loading:

```
<h1>Slim Application Error</h1>
<p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p>
<h2>Details</h2>
<div><strong>Type:</strong> Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException</div>
<div><strong>Message:</strong> Must provide source or customer.</div>
```

I can't seem to get the JSON representation of the error.

I have a try/catch block but doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
try {
   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
       "amount" => $total_amount * 100,
       "currency" => "aud",
       "customer" => $customer_id,
       "description" => 'Payment for order ID #' . $request['orderID']
   ]);
}  catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
   // Handle "hard declines" e.g. insufficient funds, expired card, etc
   // See https://stripe.com/docs/declines/codes for more
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to catch the exception type mentioned in the slim error page, "Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException"

```
try {
   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
       "amount" => $total_amount * 100,
       "currency" => "aud",
       "customer" => $customer_id,
       "description" => 'Payment for order ID #' . $request['orderID']
   ]);
}  catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
   // Handle "hard declines" e.g. insufficient funds, expired card, etc
   // See https://stripe.com/docs/declines/codes for more
}
```